# Fish and microplastic particles

Tags: ichthyology

How does exposure of fish to microplastic particles decrease egg-hatching and give young fish a craving for them?

From [Garbage in, garbage out: marine plastic 2016-06-24 | Espresso](https://espresso.economist.com/351869bde8b9d6ad1e3090bd173f600d)

> There is more than just ocean beautification at stake; many creatures
>   ingest plastic, and a recent study showed that exposing fish to
>   microplastic particles not only decreases egg-hatching but also gives
>   young fish a craving for the stuff.